# C# .Net Framework - How to create nuget package for strings localization

Tags: c#, localization, nuget-package, .net-4.8

I have created a nuget package - **SampleNuget1** with ***strings.resx*** and ***strings.ar-AE.resx*** as string Resource Files, with Access specifier - public so that it can be accessed from any assembly outside. And using it like below:

```
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ar-AE");
        SampleNuget1.strings.Culture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        Console.WriteLine(SampleNuget1.strings.Key1);
```

Still, above code is returning only default strings.resx file values and not the strings.ar-AE.resx values. Not sure how to make this work.

**Note :-** If I try the same using the SampleNuget1 as a project reference in any solution, it works fine. It only returns default strings when it is used as nuget package.